# How to assign to a dictionary the exec output for a math oper in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created the following function: (the indentation might not be perfect in the example)

```
def TestFunction():
    profile_info_per_sec = {}

    profile_info_per_sec['DB CPU(s):'] = 1

(snipped)
    l, g = locals().copy(), globals().copy()

    print ('------- 1.0 Just Printing the Value -------')
    varprint = 'print(' + 'float(' + str(finalvar) + '))'
    print ('1.0 To Be Executed: ', varprint)
    exec (varprint)
    print (locals() == l, globals() == g)
    print ('*******')

    print ('------- 2.0 Just Printing the Value -------')
    varprint = 'x=' + 'float(' + str(finalvar) + ')\nprint(x)'
    print ('2.0 To Be Executed: ', varprint)
    exec (varprint)
    print (locals() == l, globals() == g)
    print ('*******')

    print ('------- 2.1 Just Printing the Value -------')
    varprint = 'a=5\nb=7\nsum=a+b'
    print ('2.1 To Be Executed: ', varprint)
    varprint_res = {}
    exec (varprint,{},varprint_res)
    print (varprint_res)
    print (locals() == l, globals() == g)
    print ('*******')
```

This is working generating the output below:

```
------- 1.0 Just Printing the Value -------
1.0 To Be Executed:  print(float(profile_info_per_sec['DB CPU(s):']))
1.0
False True
*******
------- 2.0 Just Printing the Value -------
2.0 To Be Executed:  x=float(profile_info_per_sec['DB CPU(s):'])
print(x)
1.0
False True
*******
------- 2.1 Just Printing the Value -------
2.1 To Be Executed:  a=5
b=7
sum=a+b
{'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'sum': 12}
False True
*******
```

However, when i tried to add the following piece of code this is not working anymore.

```
 print ('------- 3.0 Capturing Value -------')
 varprint = 'x=' + 'float(' + str(finalvar) + ')\nx=x+x'
 varprint_res = {}
 print ('3.0 To Be Executed: ', varprint)
 exec (varprint,{},varprint_res)
```

The output error is:

```
------- 3.0 Capturing Value -------
3.0 To Be Executed:  x=float(profile_info_per_sec['DB CPU(s):'])
x=x+x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XmlTestCase.py", line 111, in <module>
    TestFunction()
  File "XmlTestCase.py", line 70, in TestFunction
    exec (varprint,{},varprint_res)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'profile_info_per_sec' is not defined
```

So, i know that i supposed to get the output for this in a dictionary, however, what is being executed dynamically in the code is also a dictionary and i believe the problem is related to it.

P.S: Some background information is that variable and the math operation is coming from an XML file and needs to be processed and the result should remain in the python script for further processing.

Can you guys please give me a help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Eri

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to `exec()` is a dictionary that's used to look up local variables, instead of the normal local variables of the function. So you need to add `profile_info_per_sec` to it so that `exec()` can find that variable.

```
varprint_res = { 'profile_info_per_sec': profile_info_per_sec }
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the help. When i add this piece of code it doesn't throw an error anymore. However, the result is not the expected. I've edited my question and added a 2.1 example. I would like to have the return of the math operation. In this case i'm getting only the text. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be printing `locals()` and `globals()`, because you're replacing `locals()` with the `varprint_res` variable.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks again. I did remove from the code all mention to locals() and globals(). However, it still not providing the results as in the example 2.1. I'm trying to get back an dictionary just like that: {'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'sum': 12} from example 2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? I'm not sure how the `2.1` example relates to the dictionary.

Comment: In the 2.1 example i'm putting all variables from the math operation in the dictionary called varprint_res, then i'm printing it in the code. The output is {'a': 5, 'b': 7, 'sum': 12}.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Hi Barmar, the problem actually is that in the example 2.1 i can store all variables (including the result) of my math operation from my EXEC statement in a dictionary called varprint_res, then i'm able to print it and/or manipulate at will in the code after the EXEC. However, in the example 3 i'm trying to apply the same logic, but it's just not working throwing that error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In example 3 you're trying to access the variable `profile_info_per_sec` that isn't in the dictionary. That's why you need to put it in the dictionary before calling `exec()`.